# How to close tabs with animation in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox4

Moving my extension to Firefox 4, I noticed my old code closes tabs immediately :

```
gBrowser.removeTab(tab)
```

While in Firefox 4, tabs are being closed with some animation if the process was initiated by a user.
 How to programmatically close tabs in the same manner?

Comment: I'm having the same thing happen but personally it doesn't bother me or the people who use my extension. Is there a reason you want to slow the tab down and have it animate?

Comment: A customer asked for it and I agree with her because all the features should behave consistently. Once animation is turned on it should be turned on everywhere and vice versa.

Comment: Can you consider disabling the tab animation part in Firefox 4 ?

Comment: I just don't think it's worth it, it's just eye candy after all it's not like the tab functionality doesn't work. One thing you can try is accessing the window document that contains the XULElements and try closing the tab from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same question and found the answer somewhere else...

```
gBrowser.removeTab(tab, {animate: true});
```

And you probably already know that the preference is `browser.tabs.animate`.